# Keras fit model: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I implement following code. It successfully works in previous version of Keras:

```
max_sequence = 56
input_dim = 26    

print("Build model..1")
first_input = Input(shape=(max_sequence,input_dim))
first_lstm = LSTM(5, return_sequences=True)(first_input)
first_bn = BatchNormalization()(first_lstm)
first_activation = Activation('tanh')(first_bn)
first_flat = Flatten()(first_activation)

print("Build model..2")
second_input = Input(shape=(max_sequence,input_dim))
second_lstm = LSTM(5, return_sequences=True)(second_input)
second_bn = BatchNormalization()(second_lstm)
second_activation = Activation('tanh')(second_bn)
second_flat = Flatten()(second_activation)

merge=concatenate([first_flat, second_flat])
merge_dense=Dense(3)(merge)
merge_bn = BatchNormalization()(merge_dense)
merge_activation = Activation('tanh')(merge_bn)
merge_dense2=Dense(1)(merge_activation)
merge_activation2 = Activation('tanh')(merge_dense2)

train_x_1 = np.reshape(np.array(train_x_1), [2999, 56, 26])
train_x_2 = np.reshape(np.array(train_x_2), [2999, 56, 26])


model=Model(inputs=[train_x_1,train_x_2], outputs=train_y_class)

optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.5)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])



history = model.fit([train_x_1, train_x_2], train_y_class, nb_epoch=300, batch_size=128,
                    validation_data=([val_x_1, val_x_2], val_y_class))
```

When running:

```
history = model.fit([train_x_1, train_x_2], train_y_class, nb_epoch=300, batch_size=128,
                    validation_data=([val_x_1, val_x_2], val_y_class))
```

the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' accours.
```

So I checked `train_x_1`, `train_x_2`, `train_y_class`. Their type is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. I have searched for a solution, so I tried to change type to tuple but It didn't work.

If `numpy.ndarray` is unhashable, what type of input does `model.fit` receive?

The shape of train data is as follows:

```
train_x_1.shape
(2999, 56, 26)
train_x_2.shape
(2999, 56, 26)
train_y_class.shape
(2999, 1)
```

A sample of `train_x_1` is like below:

```
array([[[ 1.62601626e-02,  2.26890756e-01,  1.17764920e-02, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 1.62601626e-02,  2.26890756e-01,  1.17764920e-02, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 1.62601626e-02,  2.26890756e-01,  1.17764920e-02, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        ...,
        [ 1.62601626e-02,  2.26890756e-01,  1.17764920e-02, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 1.62601626e-02,  2.26890756e-01,  1.17764920e-02, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
        [ 1.62601626e-02,  2.26890756e-01,  1.17764920e-02, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00]],
```

Comment: Is the type of the individual elements of `train_x_1, train_x_2, train_y_class` also `numpy.ndarray`? That may be the issue. If that is the case, you should use a tensor, rather than a nested ndarray. Can you post a sample of the content of those three variables?

Comment: @DanielR. I posted the shape of train data and sample of train_x_1. Should I use tensor? hmm..

Comment: No, ok, I assumed the error would be thrown because you were using some np.array of np.arrays, but this is not the case. Is the shape of the input defined in `Input(shape=(max_sequence,input_dim))` consistent with the input you are providing? Also, if `train_x_1` and `train_x_2` are supposed to be inputs to the same model, it's better to [np.stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack) them and feed the stacked array to the model, not pass both tensors as elements of a list. `train_x_1 = np.reshape(np.array(train_x_1)` Why are you calling np.array?

Comment: @DanielR. Thanks to reply. Actually I will tune hyperparameter of each LSTM using Bayesian optimization. So, two models are not same. max_sequence = 56, input_dim = 26. In my case, what shape should i use..? I think I have to use np.array of np.array..

Comment: @DanielR. Sorry. I had typo. What type should I use?

Comment: There are still some pieces of code missing. It is not clear for example how are you adding the various layers that you have instantiated in the first half of the code to the model `model`. Can you post the full code, so that we can replicate it and debug it?

Comment: @DanielR. I added some codes. After I implement it successfully, I apply hyper parameter tuning algorithm to it. So, this code is so simple because it is base code. The first model consists of 1 LSTM layer. The second model consists of 1 LSTM layer. Combining(Concatenating) the results of two LSTM model, two dense layer is applied. Because its task is binary prediction, the number of final node is one. After generate (2999,56,26) data, you can debug it. If you need other codes, please ask me freely. Thanks a lot.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are directly passing the input and output arrays (and not the input and output tensors) to `Model` class when constructing your model:

```
model = Model(inputs=[train_x_1,train_x_2], outputs=train_y_class)
```

Instead, you need to pass the corresponding input and output tensors like this:

```
model = Model(inputs=[first_input,second_input], outputs=merge_activation2)
```